# iOS set UIImage with animation

Tags: ios, uiimage

I'm trying to set the image of an UIImageView with an alternative image. 
I know I can do [imageView setImage: image]. However, is it possible to add any dissolve effect(animation) when I change image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UIView's `transitionWithView` method for achieving this.

A sample code snippet:

```
UIImage * newImage= [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImg.png"];
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view
              duration:3.0f
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
            animations:^{
              yourImageView.image = newImage;
            } completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done this earlier and here is the piece of code that helps you out.This code works fine for the issue you described above.

```
-(void)changeImage
{
        myImageView.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithArray:self.yourImageArray];
        myImageView.animationDuration=10.0;
        myImageView.animationRepeatCount=0;
        [myImageView startAnimating];
        myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
        [self.view addSubview:myImageView];
        //The timers time interval is the imageViews animation duration devided by the       number of images in the animationImages array. 20/5 = 4
        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(onTimer)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];

        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [timer fire];

}
```

//This will Fade in and fade Out Images.

```
-(void)onTimer{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{
            myImageView.alpha = 0.0;
        }];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            myImageView.alpha = 1.0;
        }];
    }
```

If you want cross Dissolve you can use this UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve.
Hope this will help you out if not please feel free ask.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it is a little over kill for what I am trying to do. It will be very useful for something else in the future.

Comment: You are Welcome.If your issue didn't solved yet.Explain your requirement such i will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using CAAnimation transitions

the effect you are looking for is called `kCATransitionFade`

Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CAAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [here](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/100982-caanimation-tutorial.html) for some handy tutorials as well as the class reference.